# From object make key prop react js

Tags: reactjs

I have this

```js
const allAlerts = () => {
    const alertsData2 =

    [
        [
            {
                propertyValue: 'bgColor="red"',
            },
             {
                    propertyValue: 'alignSelf="center"'
               },
        ]
    ]
    return allAlerts
```

And after I iterate from this

```js
{
    allAlerts().map((alerts, index) => {
        return (
            <>
                {alerts.map((propertyValue, onClick) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                           
                            <Alert onClick={onClick && onClick}   propertyValue>Alert Default</Alert>
                        </div>
        )
    })}
</>
)

})
```

I need to be able that propertyValue to send as a key prop so to be similar to bgColor="red"
you see down I replaced bgColor="red". But for some reason passing it propertyValue is not working

<Alert onClick={onClick && onClick}   bgColor="red">Alert Default

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, and you cannot have `onClick` inside `map`. Please elaborate more what you try to achieve.

Comment: @shkurta the part of your code `...alerts.map((propertyValue, onClick)...` has wrong parameters naming to say the least, `propertyValue` refers to the current "element" in the array that is being looped over, while your `onClick` parameter is the "index" of that current element in the array.